# How to handle events for options menu in Python (Android)?

Tags: android, python

I'm getting started in Python development for Android. I have created a simple options menu and I want a function to be called when a menu item is selected.

```
import android
droid = android.Android()

droid.addOptionsMenuItem("Show list","showList","showList","ic_media_record")
droid.addOptionsMenuItem("Exit","exit","exit","ic_media_stop")

def showList():
    print("Show list event handler")

while True: 
    response=droid.eventWait().result
    if response["name"]=="showList":
        showList
    if response["name"]=="exit":
        exit
```

Menu is visible but the funtion is not called. 
What is the easiest and standard method to handle events?